# Heroku runs ok local but deployment app crash flask and python

Tags: python, heroku, flask, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy this super actually silly app.

still, have no idea what i am doing wrong.

```
    __import__(module)
2018-06-06T02:39:57.219756+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/main.py", line 1, in <module>
2018-06-06T02:39:57.219757+00:00 app[web.1]: from flaskr import create_app
2018-06-06T02:39:57.219762+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app'
2018-06-06T02:39:57.219911+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-06-06 02:39:57 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2018-06-06T02:39:57.249096+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-06-06 02:39:57 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2018-06-06T02:39:57.249207+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-06-06 02:39:57 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boo
```

that's heroku's error log.

this is my Procfile

```
web: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT main:create_app
```

And my colder routes looks something likes this...

/pysomething/flasrk/"heres goes my files"

Weird thing is that heroku local works ok. But when deploy it crashes.

Answer (score -1):

Check your build pack is python, be sure to include your requirements.txt and check the other important check items in the build list from this article https://medium.com/the-andela-way/deploying-your-flask-application-to-heroku-c99050bce8f9

Comment: well, did that. but still the issue being from flaskr import create_app can't import name create_app

Comment: `certifi==2018.4.16
click==6.7
Flask==1.0.2
gunicorn==19.8.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
pipenv==2018.5.18
virtualenv==16.0.0
virtualenv-clone==0.3.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1`

Comment: Check your issue against this post and see if your error logs follow this, I am kinda at a loss without you shairing the complete file to see why you would be importing look this over https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/issues/26

Comment: hi, that above is my whole project